# Bialgebra and Hopf algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

I'm reading ''HOPF ALGEBRAS'' by S. Dascalescu, C. Nastasescu and S. Raianu. At the beginning of the four chapter the following is explained:

''Proposition 4.1.6. Let H be a finite dimensional bigalgebra. Then $H^*$ together with algebra structure which is dual to the coalgebra structure of H, and with the coalgebra structure which is dual to the algebra structure of H is a bialgebra, which is called the dual bialgebra of H''.

Proof. We denote by $\Delta $ and $\epsilon$ the comultiplication and the counit of $H,$ and by the $\delta$ and $E$ the comultiplication and the counit of $H^*.$ We racall that for $h^*\in H^*,$ we have $E(h^*) = h^*(1)$ and $\delta(h^*) = \sum h_1^*\otimes h_2^*,$ where $h^*(hg) =\sum h_1^*(h)h_2^*(g) $ for any $h, g\in H.$ Let us show that $\delta$ is a morphism of algebra. Indeed, if $h^*, g^*\in H^*$ and $\delta(h^*) = \sum h_1^*\otimes h_2^*,$ $\delta(g^*) = \sum g_1^* \otimes g_2^*,$ then for any $h, g\in H,$ we have
$$ \begin{array}{lll}
(h^*g^*)(hg) &=& \sum h^*(h_1g_1)g ^*(h_2g_2)\\
&=&\sum h_1^*(h_1)h_2^*(g_1)g_1^*(h_2)g_2^*(g_2)\\
&=& \sum (h_1^*g_1^*)(h) (h_2^*g_2^*)(g).
\end{array}$$

My question is why  $$(h^*g^*)(hg) = \sum h^*(h_1g_1)g ^*(h_2g_2) ?$$ $$ (h_1^*g_1^*)(h)  = h_1^*(h_1)g_1^*(h_2)  ?$$

Thank you advance!

Answer (score 4):

The multiplication of $H^*$ comes from dualizing the comultiplication of $H$ as follows:
Since $\Delta \colon H \to H \otimes H$ is linear it induces a linear map $\Delta \colon (H \otimes H)^* \to H^*$, $f \mapsto f \circ \Delta$.
We have a canonical inclusion $\varphi \colon H^* \otimes H^* \to (H \otimes H)^*$ which is given on simple tensors by
$$
    \varphi(h_1^* \otimes h_2^*)(g_1 \otimes g_2)
  = h^*_1(g_1) h^*_2(g_2).
$$
(Since $H$ is finite dimensional this is actually an isomorphism.)
The multiplication of $H^*$ is now given by the composition $\Delta^* \circ \varphi \colon H^* \otimes H^* \to H^*$.
This multiplication can also be described explicitely on elements:
For $h^*_1, h^*_2 \in H^*$ and $g \in H$ with $\Delta(g) = \sum_{(g)} g_1 \otimes g_2$ we have
$$
  (h^*_1 h^*_2)(g) = \sum_{(g)} h^*_1(g_1) h^*_2(g_2).
$$
This does in particular explain the second formula.

For the first formula we also have to use that $\Delta \colon H \to H \otimes H$ is multiplicative:
Given that $\Delta(h) = \sum_{(h)} h_1 \otimes h_2$ and $\Delta(g) = \sum_{(g)} g_1 \otimes g_2$ we find that
$$
    \Delta(hg)
  = \Delta(h) \Delta(g)
  = \left( \sum_{(h)} h_1 \otimes h_2 \right)
    \left( \sum_{(g)} g_1 \otimes g_2 \right)
  = \sum_{(h),(g)} (h_1 g_1) \otimes (h_2 g_2).
$$
By using the previous explicit formula for the multiplication of $H^*$ we find that
\begin{align*}
    (h^* g^*)(h g)
 &= \sum_{(h),(g)} h^*(h_1 g_1) g^*(h_2 g_2)
 \\
 &= \sum_{(h),(g),(h^*),(g^*)} h^*_1(h_1) h^*_2(g_1) g^*_1(h_2) g^*_2(g_2)
 \\
 &= \sum_{(h^*), (g^*)}
    \left(
      \sum_{(h)} h^*_1(h_1) g^*_1(h_2)
    \right)
    \left(
      \sum_{(g)} h^*_2(g_1) g^*_2(g_2)
    \right)
  \\
  &= \sum_{(h^*), (g^*)} (h^*_1 g^*_1)(h) (h^*_2 g^*_2)(g).
\end{align*}

Comment: @ Jendrik Stelzner. Thanks! Because $(H, m, \mu, \Delta, \epsilon)$  is a bigalgebra , we have $$ \epsilon(hg) = \epsilon(h)\epsilon(g),\forall h, g\in H$$ Hence $$ \Delta_{H^*}(\epsilon) = \epsilon \otimes \epsilon$$ Why  $\Delta_{H^*}(\epsilon) = \epsilon \otimes \epsilon$?

Comment: The element $\Delta_{H^*}(\epsilon) = \sum_{(\epsilon)} \epsilon_1 \otimes \epsilon_2$ is defined by the property that $\epsilon(hg) = \sum_{(\epsilon)} \epsilon_1(h) \epsilon_2(g)$ for all $g, h \in H$. Since $\epsilon(hg) = \epsilon(h) \epsilon(g)$ (as $\epsilon$ is an algebra morphism, and therefore in particular multiplicative) we see that the simple tensor $\epsilon \otimes \epsilon$ already satisfies this property. Thus $\Delta_{H^*}(\epsilon) = \epsilon \otimes \epsilon$. (This shows more generally that $\Delta_{H^*}(h^*) = h^* \otimes h^*$ if and only if $h^*$ is multiplicative.)

Comment: @ Jendrik Stelzner. Thanks! Because $$ \Delta_{\mathscr{H}^*}^*(\varphi\psi) = \sum\limits_{(\varphi), (\psi)}(\varphi_1\psi_1)  \otimes_{\mathbb{K}}(\varphi_2\psi_2).$$
and $(\varphi\psi)(hg) = \sum\limits_{(\varphi), (\psi)}(\varphi_1\psi_1)(h)(\varphi_2\psi_2)(g)$ với mọi $h, g\in \mathscr{H}$ 

Hence
$$  \Delta_{\mathscr{H}^*}^*(\varphi). \Delta_{\mathscr{H}^*}^*(\psi) = \left(\sum\limits_{(\varphi)}\varphi_1  \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} \varphi_2\right). \left(\sum\limits_{(\psi)}\psi_1  \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} \psi_2\right) = \Delta_{\mathscr{H}^*}^*(\varphi\psi).?$$

Comment: @ Jendrik Stelzner.  Why $$\left(\sum\limits_{(\varphi)}\varphi_1  \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} \varphi_2\right). \left(\sum\limits_{(\psi)}\psi_1  \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} \psi_2\right) = \Delta_{\mathscr{H}^*}^*(\varphi\psi) ?$$

Comment: that is a nice and detailed explanation +1.